# How to add a people picker textbox/control on a page in O365 site

Tags: office-365, people-picker

How to add a people picker textbox/control on a page  in O365 site that will take the name of the users who have access to the site.

Comment: on which page, you want to add people picker textbox/control?

Comment: i have added an aspx page that will have a user input form(some labels and textbox controls) i need an option to add an approver that shoudl be a user who has access to the site.

Comment: There may be lots of users who do have an access to the site. do you want them all?

Comment: yes currently i am looking for both, for all users and for specific group if any created(like Approvers)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use the **client-side People Picker control**.

From MSDN:

> The client-side People Picker control lets users quickly search for
>   and select valid user accounts for people, groups, and claims in their
>   organization. The picker is an HTML and JavaScript control that
>   provides cross-browser support. Adding the picker to your add-in is
>   easy: In your markup, add a container element for the control and
>   references for the control and its dependencies. Then in your script,
>   call the SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper global
>   function to render and initialize the picker.

See the complete article with sample code [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx).

Comment: The HTML part "SharePoint:ScriptLink name=" gives error, what am i missing

Comment: Which error? ...

Comment: <asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
says Sharepoint is unrecognized tag

Comment: Where are you building the page?

Comment: i am creating a provider hosted app for 0365 portal from visual studio. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Very strange. I do not know what the problem is. I would recommend you do another question with that error. I'm sure someone must have gone through this before.

Comment: like we have asp tag by default on aspx page, do we have sharepoint tag also by default?